# Como armazenar variaveis em arquivos.txt

Tags: c, configuração

Sou iniciante em C e estou procurando estudar como deixar meu programa ja configurado toda vez que for executado.

Me parece algo bem importante, mas achei pouco material.

Por exemplo, **"lembrar"** qual era o ultimo DIR em que meu programa estava "lendo", quando for reexecutar.

como guardar e recuperar a var "dir" em um arquivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muitas dores, encontrei esse artigo no VOL... falando dessa LibConfuse: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Criando-programas-com-suporte-a-arquivos-de-configuracao-com-a-libConfuse

Alguém já usou? conhece? recomenda?

vou começar a estudá-lo...  quem sabe, seja mais "facil"

Answer (score 3):

Para gravar arquivos em C, você pode usar as funções `fopen`, `fwrite` e `fclose` (incluídas no header `stdio.h`).

Aqui há um exemplo prático sobre como gravar e ler dados em um arquivo: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm

Comment: Ola @astorga,  obrigada pela ajuda, mas eu procuro "uma tecnica" mais comunmente usada para trabalhar com arquivos  gravando e recuperarand as variaveis...   por exemplo **como achar** 1 das 100 variaveis que armazenei, entende?

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto nesse caso você pode pesquisar por serialização, acho que vai fazer mais sentido pra você. Arquivos .conf normalmente são simples de interpretar: os caracteres `#` são ignorados e os nomes de parâmetros são separados por uma quantidade arbitrária de espaços até o primeiro caractere. Se você já consegue ler e gravar em arquivos, interpretar um arquivo .conf não deve ser um problema pra você ;)

Comment: mas de qualquer forma, vou ter que "varrer" o arquivo.. procurando a string da minha var e ao que ela eh "igualada" ? certo?... trabalhoso... neh?

Comment: É precisamente o que qualquer parser vai fazer por você. O que normalmente acontece é que eles expõem essa configuração em formato de dicionário ou alguma estrutura mais simples. Dependendo do seu propósito, [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig.html) pode te ajudar (apesar de fazer muito mais do que só isso).

Comment: Nossa? pra que negativaram você? sua resposta não valeu?  Pois me foi de grande ajuda(embora não tenha resolvido meu problema)! Obrigado, acho que você se manteve no assunto!

Comment: @astorga propôs ajudar e sua resposta não pode ser considerada errada, por isso voto +1

Comment: boa atitude! valeu!  @wendell... soh um comentario.. tenho visto uma certa "coisa estranha":  o pessoal negativando o que tem haver com o assunto, e positivanto respostas totalmente fora do escopo... inclusive algumas ateh ofensivas de tao agressivas que sao.... pena...

Answer (score 3):

Não existe uma maneira automática de fazer isso, tem que ser programado explicitamente.

Na saída normal do programa você grava em um arquivo de sua escolha os dados que você acha que vão ser necessários na próxima ativação do programa, e na ativação você lê o arquivo e executa as ações necessárias de acordo com o que foi lido, por exemplo, mudar o diretório corrente da aplicação.

Para não ter que reinventar a roda é possível utilizar um formato padrão, como JSON e "ini", mas neste caso vai valer mais a pena utilizar uma biblioteca externa para fazer a leitura e gravação dos arquivos, pois existem muitas dessas bibliotecas disponíveis.

Alternativamente você pode usar o banco de dados embutido SQLITE, mas neste caso o arquivo de configuração não será em modo texto. Acho que esta é uma alternativa interessante.

Obs. o ambiente Windows já fornece funções prontas para acesso a arquivos "ini". Então especificamente para o Windows é muito fácil usar arquivos "ini".

Comment: entao eu teria que "procurar" uma string no arquivo, que seja a minha variavel, e depois "ler" aquilo quem depois dela (o valor da var)?  tudo escrito na unha? que triste...

Comment: @Camila Yamamoto: atualizei minha resposta, por favor dê uma olhada.

Comment: nossa, entendi, vai dar trabalho

Comment: @Camila Yamamoto: Vai. :)

Comment: @Camila Yamamoto: mas veja a edição que fiz na resposta.

Comment: Obrigada!  li tudo! Ja estou estudando!